# Passing a commandline parameter containing quotes to installer

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to pass a custom commandline parameter to an installer created with Inno Setup. The parameter value actually consists of several parameters that will be used to launch the installed program when installation is complete, so the value contains spaces as well as quotes to group together parameters.

For example, when `-arg "C:\path with spaces" -moreargs` should be used as `Parameters` in a `[Run]` section entry, I would like to launch the installer like this:

```
setup.exe /abc="-arg "C:\path with spaces" -moreargs"
```

Outputting the parameters that the installer receives in a `[Code]` section via `ParamStr()` shows them (of course) split up: `/abc=-arg C:\path`, `with`, `spaces -moreargs`

How do I escape the quotes to retain them?

I tried doubling the inner quotes:

```
setup.exe /abc="-arg ""C:\path with spaces"" -moreargs"
```

This correctly keeps the parameter together (`/abc=-arg C:\path with spaces -moreargs`), however it seems that `ParamStr()` removes all quotes.

Is there a way to retain quotes within a parameter retrieved with `ParamStr()` or a param constant `{param:abc|DefaultValue}`?

Alternatives seem to be to either do my own parameter parsing from `GetCmdTail` (which contains the original parameter string) or use another character instead of the inner quotes that are retained in `ParamStr()` and then replace them with quotes afterwards. But I would prefer not doing that if there is a way to use the built-in functions.

Comment: Indeed `ParamStr` is dumb, so you have to go for one of your  alternative solutions.

Comment: Or change your logic. Break down the parameter into several. Then put them back together for the function call.

Comment: Not that it helps you, but I wish JSON strings were supported for passing in command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems both `{param}` and `ParamStr()` strip out double quotes, but as you pointed out (thanks!) the `GetCmdTail` function returns the original.

So here's a function to get the original parameters with quotes:

```
function ParamStrWithQuotes(ParamName: String) : string;
var
  fullCmd : String;
  currentParamName : string;
  i : Integer;
  startPos : Integer;
  endPos : Integer;
begin

  fullCmd := GetCmdTail
  // default to end of string, in case the option is the last item
  endPos := Length(fullCmd);

  for i := 0 to ParamCount-1 do
  begin
    // extract parameter name (eg, "/Option=")
    currentParamName := Copy(ParamStr(i), 0, pos('=',ParamStr(i)));

    // once found, we want the following item
    if (startPos > 0) then 
    begin 
      endPos := pos(currentParamName,fullCmd)-2; // -1 to move back to actual end position, -1 for space
      break; // exit loop
    end;

    if (CompareText(currentParamName, '/'+ParamName+'=') = 0) then // case-insensitive compare 
    begin
      // found target item, so save its string position
      StartPos := pos(currentParamName,fullCmd)+2+Length(ParamName);
    end;
  end;

  if ((fullCmd[StartPos] = fullCmd[EndPos])
     and ((fullCmd[StartPos] = '"') or (fullCmd[StartPos] = ''''))) then
  begin
    // exclude surrounding quotes
    Result := Copy(fullCmd, StartPos+1, EndPos-StartPos-1);
  end
  else 
  begin
    // return as-is
    Result := Copy(fullCmd, StartPos, EndPos-StartPos+1);
  end;
end;
```

You can access this with `{code:ParamStrWithQuotes|abc}`

When invoking the setup.exe, you do have to escape the quotes, so one of the following works for that:

```
setup.exe /abc="-arg ""C:\path with spaces"" -moreargs"
```

or

```
setup.exe /abc='-arg "C:\path with spaces" -moreargs'
```